# Using Python to find noun phrase and dependency

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, textblob

I'm trying to find a noun phrase from a set of sentences and output whether the sentence is true or false based on its presence.

For an example, following are four samples

```
s1 = "he reported red light"
s2 = "he found a red light at the end of the road"
s3 = "he denied to have seen red light"
s4 = "he said that the red light was absent"
```

The output which I'm looking for is "True" for s1 and s2 (because from the sentence it is clear that the red light is present", whereas "False" for s3 & s4, when the input string is "red light"

I tried using TextBlob which returns "red light" as noun phrase.

```
print(TextBlob(s1).sentences[0].pos_tags)
print(TextBlob(s1).sentences[0].noun_phrases)
```

The example above are samples which can be part of a long sentence also.
Also, there can be combinations of positive words like "present","found", "spotted","has" etc, same is the case with negative words

Also, if there are multiple noun phrases, but I want to find the presence of a particular noun phrase, how can I do it?

Comment: I'm gonna guess there will be some issues answering that because I think you are asking a grammar question more so than a coding question. It's easy to do a if statement based on position of red light and a dictionary of presence/absence of negative or positive words; it's significantly different if you require there to be grammar correction. Try something like this package: https://github.com/SKCrawford/grammar-detector that will help you first parse the sentence, and then you can apply different positive/negative rules to the sentence types.

Comment: what do you mean by "noun phrase" ? linguistically speaking, all 4 of your examples contain a noun phrase headed by "light". I do not the difference you see between [s1,s2] and [s3,s4]...